# Using a form instead of hard-coding a value?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a one-field form with a button. The field will be where the user enters his username. The value of that field will be passed into the variable `@username` in the following code:

```
def home
    require 'open-uri'

    @username = "brink" 
    @url = "http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=#{@username}"
end
```

As you can see, the `@username` variable is hard coded. I want to allow the user to input what he would like his username to be.

After that, the user should be redirected to a page where he can see the results of his search.

How would I implement such a feature? Not quite sure where to begin. What documentation can I look at to find help for this?

**What I've looked into/Comments**

1. I read up that forms essentially send POST requests. To my current understanding, I don't need a post request. All I need to do is take what the user specifies and substitute it into the URL
2. Following Rich Peck's suggestion, I have created a new Search
   controller with a home action. Then I added `get
   "search(/:username)", :to => "search#home"` to my routes.

   This is great because it makes it possible to type in **any**
   username into the browser and be returned a table of information.
   The problem, now, is that **regardless of the username I type in the
   browser**, the username that gets passed into the crawler is still
   the one that is hard coded into my controller (in this case, Brink).

   What I am looking for is a way to submit a form that will cause
   the`@username` value to change accordingly. At the very least, we
   should be able to change the link up in the browser manually and
   achieve the same result.
3. Removing `@username = "brink"` from my controller does not work.
4. Here is the form I've created:

   ```
   <%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
     <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
     <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
     <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
   <% end %>
   ```

   When I submit it, it runs the code with the hardcoded `@username`
   value. This has me thinking, though. Will every form I create in
   this application do the same thing?
5. I've pretty much gone blank. I feel so close, yet so far away. Haha. This is killing me! Guess I'll do some reading on routes and forms to see if it gets me closer to solving this problem.

Comment: Do you need to do some work within your Rails app before redirecting or is “sending the user to a page where he can see the results of his search” is all that needs to happen?

Comment: Some work needs to be done. The page the user has to be redirected to is one that's in my application. I crawled the `@url`. The user should be redirected to a page in my application that displays the contents of `@url` with his username used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting `@username` equal to `params[:username]` in the controller.

In the view, my form label and text field tag look like this:

```
<%= label_tag(:username, "Search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
```

My god Rails is magic. Found this all due to trial and error. I don't know how I would have found the answer otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

**Routes**

Your problem can be solved with some [`routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) magic:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "search(/:username)", :to => "search#home"
```

This will pass the variable `params[:username]` every time you send a request to `http://hiscore.runescape.com/search/your_user_name`

---

**JS**

All I would do to make this work is handle the form submit with JS:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("user_form").on("submit", function() {
     window.location.href = "/search/" + $("input").val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Rich... I've added your code to my application. What does my form need to look like?

Comment: I'll do some research until you get back. And I'lll edit my original post accordingly.

Comment: Yeah... I've got literally zero knowledge with JavaScript, so that part is all magic to me.